how to properly create a new style in lyx
im using LyX version 2.4 and I want to creat a new Style called "Reminder" and be able to translate it to hebrew.
I've created a file as an example called more-layouts.inc in .lyx/layouts and reconfigured but it didnt work.
also how can add "Reminder" to each reminder paragram like in proof theorm etc.?
Style MyQuotation
Category              MainText
Margin                Static
LatexType             Environment
LatexName             myquotation
NextNoIndent          1
LeftMargin            MMM
RightMargin           MMM
ParIndent             MM
ParSkip               0
ItemSep               0
TopSep                0.5
BottomSep             0.5
ParSep                0
Align                 Block
AlignPossible         Block, Left, Right, Center
Preamble
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newenvironment{myquotation}
  {\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=red]\quotation}
  {\endquotation\end{mdframed}}
EndPreamble

End
